# Umbraco class library and Web Site

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I have a project I was brought onto a few years ago and the original developer is no longer available. We have an Umbraco 6 based website. The solution has two projects, a Web Site and a class library call Umbraco.Extensions. I believe I read some conventional wisdom pertaining to Umbraco at some point where it is recommended to split it up like this but I am looking for more information about this particular style of setup and how it is supposed to work. For example right now I am dealing with a missing assembly issue, and i fixed it by copying a dll from the bin of Extensions to the bin of the Web Site. How is this handled regularly?

Comment: Also i am trying to migrate my dlls to nuget packages so I can delete my bin folder and have it rebuild, but I have no build on Site so how does that work?

Answer (score 0):

it's generally a good idea to keep the projects separated. You should have some kind of automation (maybe a post-build action) to copy the dll of the class library to the bin of the umbraco project. Or maybe rebuild the umbraco project with the correct references, but I dont usually do that.

Comment: Well on build of Extensions, (for that matter, I only build Extensions, the Web Site is not set up to be built) I copy the Extensions DDL, the XML, and the UsersControls folder, as a post-build event. But what I was talking about was a logging assembly for example, a third party library, I decided to use to do some logging, do i need to reference this now in both projects?

Comment: I guess you should include your logging assembly in the list of the postbuild files to copy.
As a side note, you can use the log service already availabile in umbraco(Log4Net) by getting his reference in your code
    ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(
                MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
            );

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976406/using-nuget-with-dll-refresh-files-in-asp-net-web-site-projects-with-web-dep
Is it likely this is whats happening? All the dependent dlls are being copied to bin in Web Site?